# How to concatenate values for the same key in selecting from a json based har file using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq, har

I am trying to generate a `.csv` file from processing a `.har` (JSON based) file.

My current command is like this (note that I need to have `ascii_downcase` as name is found in upper, lower and Initcaps):

```sh
    cat "$har1".har | $jq -r '[ "Name", "StartTime", "Cache", "Encoding", "ECID", "Method", "Size", "Time", "Blocked", "Send", "Wait", "Receive", "Type" ], (.log.entries[] | [
        .request.url,
        .startedDateTime,
        ((.response.headers[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value) // ""),
        ((.response.headers[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "content-encoding").value) // ""),
        ((.response.headers[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "x-oracle-dms-ecid").value) // ""),
            .request.method,
        (if .response.bodySize == 0 then .response.content.size else .response.bodySize end),
        .time,
        .timings.blocked,
        .timings.send,
        .timings.wait,
        .timings.receive,
        ._resourceType ]) | @csv' > "$har1".csv
```

The har snippet that is causing issues in the response, is multiple entries for "Cache-Control", Like below:

```json
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=31536000"
        },
```

In the following portion of json:

```json
    "response": {
      "status": 200,
      "statusText": "OK",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Thu, 06 May 2021 04:53:24 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "Oracle-HTTP-Server"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-XSS-Protection",
          "value": "1; mode=block"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=31536000"
        },
```

The values could be anything, so do not want to hard code anything. The current result due to this in `.csv` is like:

```
"public","max-age=31536000"
```

they are split as 2 columns.

```
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","public","max-age=31536000","gzip"...
```

I need to get this as:

```
"public;max-age=31536000"
```

with `;` as separator, but in same column of `.csv`.

```
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","public;max-age=31536000","gzip"...
```

I tried `groups_by`, `group_by` examples, but got errors one way or another.

oguz ismail's suggestion had unequal "(" and ")".

I tried using various combinations based on the suggestion, and realize:

1. It still does not merge the columns as desired with ";" into one column in the generated .csv.
2. It has added 3 null columns before and 6 after the .name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control" column.

Original code:

```
((.response.headers[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value) // ""),
Original response:
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","public","max-age=31536000","gzip",

Expected response:
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","public;max-age=31536000","gzip",
```

first attempt:

```
((.response.headers[] | ([select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value]) | join(";")) // ""),
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","","","","public","max-age=31536000","","","","","","","gzip",
```

second attempt:

```
((.response.headers[] | [select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value] | join(";")) // ""),
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","","","","public","max-age=31536000","","","","","","","gzip"
```

third attempt:

```
((.response.headers[] | [(select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value)] | join(";")) // ""),
"xx.js","2021-05-06T06:14:10.505Z","","","","public","max-age=31536000","","","","","","","gzip",
```

Comment: I have tried reformatting a bit, but not sure if I got it all right.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I retried re-formatting again, hopefully got it better this time.

Comment: `([select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value)] | join(";")) // ""` should do the trick.

Comment: This one works:  ([.response.headers[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value] | join(";")),

Answer (score 0):

Your general problem is that `.response.headers[]` produces multiple results and you have nothing to gather those results into a single value. You can either wrap an array construction around the expression, i.e. `[.response.headers[]| <...more filters here> ]`, or you can use `map` instead of the `[]` operator.

Using an array constructor:

```
([.response.headers[] | select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value] | join(";"))
```

Using map:

```
(.response.headers | map(select(.name | ascii_downcase == "cache-control").value | join(";"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the first construct successfully.